# len() is not giving me the right result

Tags: go

The lenght of s1 and s2 should be the same after concatenating "-" to the string to have the same lenght

```
package main
import . "fmt"

func stamp(s1 string, s2 string) (result string){
  if len(s1) > len(s2) {
    for i := 0; i < (len(s1) - len(s2)); i++{
      s2 += "-"
    }
  } else if len(s1) < len(s2) {
    for i := 0; i < (len(s2) - len(s1)); i++ {
      s1 += "-"
    }
  }

  for i := 0; i < len(s2); i++ {
    result += string(s1[i]) + string(s2[i])
  }
  return
}

func main(){
  var s1, s2 string
  Print("Insert 2 words: ")
  Scan(&s1, &s2)
  Println(stamp(s1,s2))
}
```

Tried s1 as "esame"
s2 as "go"
stamp got egsoa-m- // should be egsoa-m-e-

Tried s2 as "go"
s1 as "esame"
stamp got

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 4



goroutine 1 [running]:

main.stamp(...)

    /home/Usr/Info/es19.go:16

main.main()

    /home/Usr/Info/es19.go:25 +0x2ac

exit status 2
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/xMWZuvO7M9S or https://go.dev/play/p/7s5dhaJ2xL_j or https://go.dev/play/p/7EWZeJ5ctoP

Answer (score 1):

This is a common programing pitfall which is that you shouldn't modify an/a array/slice while visiting it. In this case, you try to append '-' to s1/s2 while the for-loop depends on the subtraction of len(s1) and len(s2). Let's assume the initial length of s1 and s2 to be 2 and 5, the delta is 3, after the first round, length of s1 becomes 3 and the i becomes 1, the delta is 2, the loop continues. But, after the second round, length of s1 becomes 4 and i becomes 2, the delta is now 1, so the loop ends here. You may expect 3 rounds while it turns out to be 2.

More to learn is that Go's len function is dynamic called. So the solution is to add one line above the for-loop to save the initial length delta, which is the sub line below. I believe it will give what you want.

```
        if len(s1) > len(s2) {
                sub := len(s1) - len(s2)
                for i := 0; i < sub; i++ {
                        s2 += "-"
                }
        } else if len(s1) < len(s2) {
                sub := len(s2) - len(s1)
                for i := 0; i < sub; i++ {
                        s1 += "-"
                }
        }
```